# javascript turn a YouTube link into embed video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I Have Many Links On My Page All Jotted Around In Random Places. If Have The Links Like This:

```
<a href="https://youtu.be/4tG274QuqHM" title="Go To https://youtu.be/4tG274QuqHM" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">https://youtu.be/4tG274QuqHM</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM" title="Go To https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM</a>
```

or

```
Any Other YouTube Video Link Format
```

Is There Any Way In JavaScript To Get Any Form Of YouTube Link And Turn It Into A YouTube Embed Iframe, By Using JavaScript To Make It End Up Looking Like This;

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4tG274QuqHM?autoplay=0&autohide=1&controls=2&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Could Anyone Fix This Code To Make It Work???

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var matches = $(this).attr("href").match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/);
            if(matches){
                $(this).attr("class","youtube-link");
            }
    });
    $('a.youtube-link').each(function() {
        var yt_url = this.href,
            yt_id = yt_url.split('?v=')[1],
            yt_id = yt_url.split('embed/')[1],
            yt_title = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<iframe style="max-width:560px;max-height:315px;" width="600" height="600" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + yt_id + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, this could be done using JavaScript..

Comment: What have you actually tried? Please show us your JavaScript code and what you expect it to do.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service - you have to try something first for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @MathiasBecher I Have Tried Really Hard And Got Some JavaScript, But It Does Not Work To Well; Can You Fix It, For Me???

Answer (score 0):

I would check this link out. It's Google's documentation on a Youtube iFrame.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the `href` value on click on the `anchor` tag and replace the existing `anchor` tag with a `iframe` tag.

```
<a href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM" title="Go To https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">https://youtube.com/watch?v=4tG274QuqHM</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" title="Go To http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k</a>
<script>
$('a').click(function(e)
{
   var target = $(this).attr('href');
   var iframe = $('<iframe/>',{ width: "420", height: "315" , src : target});
   $(this).replaceWith(iframe);
   e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/4nqhqu03/

Comment: It Does Not Work To Well

Comment: Could You Review My Javascript Code Above